# For hydrogen atom wave function, why eigenstate of Hamiltonian isn't only spherical harmonics if $H$ commutes with square of angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, hydrogen, orbitals

I was reading quantum mechanics and I read about CSCO. So, commuting operators should share common eigen states, does that mean same eigen states? because in hydrogen atom wave function, Hamiltonian and square angular momentum operator commute. But I don't write eigenstate of $H$ as only the spherical harmonics (the eigenstates of $L^2$) but there is a radial part included. does that mean commutation doesn't mean same eigenstates. I am confused here

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: When you have commuting operators, then simultaneous eigenfunctions exist spanning the entire Hilbert space. Nobody said that the eigenfunctions do not have separable parts, or that the operators are acting on all parts at once. $\hat L^2$ clearly only acts upon the angular parts, whereas $\hat{\mathcal H}$ acts on the whole wavefunction.